# Error when searching in the new UITableViewDiffableDataSource [Snapshotting]

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, snapshot, diffabledatasource

I know that this is a common error and has been discussed many times, but hear me out. I've read a LOT of those posts and none of them mentions my specific case and I haven't been able to figure the solution out by myself.

This is the error I'm getting:

`[Snapshotting] Snapshotting a view (0x7fab10c300b0, _UIReplicantView) that has not been rendered at least once requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.`

According to my observation it appears everytime I **begin searching in the searchController**. It seems to me, that the error pops up when the keyboard changes (from capital to small letters, vice versa...).

### **I've tried:**

- putting `.layoutIfNeeded()` everywhere I possibly could (tableView, cells, view, searchBar...)
- all UI changes are happening on main thread
- toying with different `searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.becomeFirstResponder()`

Needless to say, none of the above solved my issue.

**Here is my code for searching:**

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        let added = DBManager.shared.getAddedCurrencies()
        DispatchQueue.main.async { searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.becomeFirstResponder() }
        guard let filter = searchController.searchBar.text, !filter.isEmpty else {
            filtering = false
            filtered = []
            updateDiffable(with: added)
            return
        }
        filtering = true
        filtered = added.filter({ (currency) -> Bool in
            return currency.name.lowercased().contains(filter.lowercased()) || currency.code.lowercased().contains(filter.lowercased())
        })

        updateDiffable(with: filtered)

    }
```

**Updating diffable data source**

```
func updateDiffable(with list: [Currency], animate: Bool = true) {
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Currency>()
        snapshot.appendSections([.main])
        snapshot.appendItems(list)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.diffableDataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: animate)
        }
    }
```

As I said, error pops up precisely when I put first letter into search bar or when I remove it. Otherwise everything works just fine.

Any help or tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try to remove the DispatchQueue block in `updateDiffable`. The diffable data source handles that itself.

Comment: @vadian thanks for the comment. This unfortunately leads to Xcode yelling at me even more. But I appreciate the effort! :)